# How to add props in the component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, react-functional-component

I am using this above Flatlist with a component. So here I am saying an icon in the variable back. I want to send some color to this svg icon from {item.back}. How can i do this so that if any conditions change I will send a color to Icons and change its color?

```
const data = [{ back: <Icon/>}]

<FlatList
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
  data={data}
  renderItem={() => <Item />}
/>;

const Item_view = ({ item, index }) => {
  const { navigateTo } = item;
  return <View>{item.back}</View>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In generally, Use your SVG as a component, then all the SVG goodness is accessible:

 For example:

```
const MenuIcon = (props) =>(
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill={props.fill} className={props.class}></svg>
)
```

And in your render

```
<li>
   <a href="/" className="sidebar__link">
      <MenuIcon fill="white"/>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi @Liron I can use it like this. But as i am using data from constant and different icons for different flatlist data. So how can i send some color on flatlist item click